# Python: Installing Flask with MAMP

Tags: python, flask

I am going to try Flask very first time. I found [this link](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/installation/) for installation which asks me to install some virtualenv. I am using MAMP on my machine. I wonder whether I can integrate Flask with Apache. I want to later use Flask based app on my Shared hosting which just supports Apache. So I wonder whether I can use it with Apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Flask with Apache (using mod_wsgi), check the [deployment docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/mod_wsgi/).  No need to use Apache in your development machine, Flask has integrated web server, which is more convenient when developing.  Unless you want to test your webapp in an environment similar to the one you're going to deploy to, but for that using virtual machine is a better option (e.g. [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/)).

Since you say that it would be your first time using Flask, I'd suggest to forget deployment questions for awhile and simply follow the tutorial, just play with it.  When you'll have your first app ready, then you can learn more about the deployment.

Comment: could not agree more :) Just try, develop locally with built in web server. Maybe you will not like it at all :) For virtual machines simply virtualbox would work too.

Comment: My system is not so heavy that I use VMs for it. I agree with you that I need to focus on Development at this moment but I am being skeptic that I don't want to finish up my project in something that can;t run on my shared hosting which only supports Apache.

Comment: MY hosting don't support mod_wsgi. Guess I go for this solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465316/where-to-host-flask-and-alchemy-app

Comment: If your hosting provider supports FastCGI, you can use that instead: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/fastcgi/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Apache webserver, consider using [mod_wsgi.](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/mod_wsgi/)

So it seems likely that they integrate fairly well.